# How to set dynamic checkbox checked in angular js, when edit click?

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu

```
 Html Code here
```

```
<span ng-repeat="group in groups">
<input id="{{group.CFG_ORGLEVEL_ID}}" type="checkbox" value="
 {{group.CFG_ORGLEVEL_ID}}"ngmodel="formData.CFG_GROUPS_LEVEL[group.CFG_ORGLEV
EL_ID]"    ng-checked="formData.CFG_GROUPS_LEVEL.indexOf(group.CFG_ORGLEVEL_ID)
> -1"/>{{group.CFG_GROUPS_LEVEL }} </span>
```

I have use name is array.. Angular js script used for display value..That code mention here..

```
data.group_list = [{"CFG_ORGLEVEL_ID":"2", "CFG_ORGLEVEL_CODE":"MRP"},   {"CFG_ORGLEVEL_ID":"3", "CFG_ORGLEVEL_CODE":"Mkv"}];
$scope.groups =  data.group_list;
```

This is work fine but i dont know when edit time set function..I have try some format,but not work ..mention that 
code in below

```
$http.post('test/testScript.php',out)
        .success(function (data)
            {
        /* data['grouplevel'] is 2**/$scope.formData.CFG_GROUPS_LEVEL[].splice = data['grouplevel'],$scope.group[0];
 });
```

I didn't know check box set checked function in angular js..Please help me..

Comment: could it be that it's just a typo? you're having a "ngmodel" but it needs to be written "ng-model".

Comment: i have updateng-model also..but not working